# Does keep alive only matter with outbound requests?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

If I have a client that may be making a request to an http Google Cloud Function multiple times in a relatively short amount of time how can I use keep-alive? Is having the client send the connection keep-alive header enough?

I saw this on the Google docs:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking

```
const http = require('http');
const agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true});

/**
 * HTTP Cloud Function that caches an HTTP agent to pool HTTP connections.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.connectionPooling = (req, res) => {
  req = http.request(
    {
      host: '',
      port: 80,
      path: '',
      method: 'GET',
      agent: agent,
    },
    resInner => {
      let rawData = '';
      resInner.setEncoding('utf8');
      resInner.on('data', chunk => {
        rawData += chunk;
      });
      resInner.on('end', () => {
        res.status(200).send(`Data: ${rawData}`);
      });
    }
  );
  req.on('error', e => {
    res.status(500).send(`Error: ${e.message}`);
  });
  req.end();
};
```

But, that would only apply to making outbound requests from the cloud function right?

There was also something about the global (instance-wide) scope here:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips

Is there anything I need to do to reuse connections on requests sent from the end user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define `agent` at the global scope in your function, that is only retained for as long as any given server instance where that is running.  So, while your connections may keep alive in that one instance, it will not share any connections with other instances that are allocated when the load on your function increases.  You don't have much direct control over when Cloud Functions will spin up a new instance to handle new load, or when it will deallocate that instance.  You just have to accept that they will come and go over time, along with any HTTP connections that are kept alive by global scope objects.

Comment: In the given example though, isn't the agent used to make requests? How can I keep connections alive from the clients who triggered the http function? From what you are saying it sounds like incoming connections from my end users can't be reused. Which would make sense, since cloud functions can scale to 0, but if you are going to be triggering the function from the same client within a set amount of time is there a way to reuse the connection?

Comment: Are you saying that your connections are definitely not being kept alive?  If there is a problem, please describe what it is, and how you are able to reproduce it.  If there is no problem to describe, then there's not much Stack Overflow can do to help.

Comment: I haven't tested anything yet and you may be right that they are being kept alive.